# Different sized boxes won't align with flex

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I got one line with a 25%, 25% and 50% box. The next line I got two 50% boxes. I use flex to align them. But line 1 won't align as line 2-4.

[**Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/L1f3wrk5/2/)

```
.line {
    display: flex;
}
.line .col {
    margin: 5px;
}
.line .col-3 {
    width: 25%;
}
.line .col-6 {
    width: 50%;
}
.line .col-12 {
    width: 100%
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply because the margin is lower in a single element compared to two elements. Try this:

```
.line .col {
    padding: 0 5px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L1f3wrk5/5/)**

Comment: Thanks! That was the solution.

Comment: Sure thing :) Feel free to mark it as answer by clicking the check